# Map in tab with Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mapbox

I'd like to put a map from mapbox in a tab with Ionic 5. It introduces a new way of handling tabs and now every tab is linked to a route corresponding to a lazy loaded module.

I call my `createMap` method in the `ionViewDidEnter` hook to be sure that I can access the HTML element where I will create the map.

Problem is, this hook is triggered everytime the tab is selected and I need it to be created only once at first visit.

If I use `ngAfterViewInit` hook as I would do in a classic Angular app, the map is created too early to compute its dimensions to take 100% of height and width.

Any idea on how to do that?

Quick code samples:

**tab1.page.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tab1',
    templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

    map: mapboxgl.Map;

    @ViewChild('mapContainer')
    public mapContainer: ElementRef

    constructor() { }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        // create map here and load data
        // triggered on any tab visit
    }
}
```

**tabs-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'tab1',
                loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
            },
            // etc. etc.
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

Comment: From the lifecycle of the page, calling it in ngAfterViewInit would be correct to avoid loading it every time. Have you tried with an async funtion to delay loading the map?

Comment: @Moritz I tried with ngAfterViewInit and waiting for platform to be ready. Map is rendered but its dimensions are not computed correctly...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a flag (a boolean property) set to `false` until `ionViewDidEnter()` is triggered.

in the `ionViewDidEnter()` call the method that creates the map only the first time, based on the flag.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tab1',
    templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
    mapCreated = false;
    map: mapboxgl.Map;

    @ViewChild('mapContainer')
    public mapContainer: ElementRef

    constructor() { }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        // create map here and load data
        // triggered on any tab visit
        if (!this.mapCreated) {
            // call createMap...
            this.mapCreated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I already did but I'm not a big fan of that...

Comment: That's not so bad given that it's how Ionic tabs work. Please post if you find a better solution :)